# Is there any way to create folder on home screen programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I have a requirement to create a folder on homescreen. And user can able to drop some app icons to it.

Can any one please tell me how to create folder on home screen.

Comment: I think this is only available for ICS (not sure about 3.x).

Comment: yes sankar, it's possible create a live folder for app shortcuts

Comment: @imrankhan can you tell me the steps to create folder or plese provide piece of code to create folder

Answer (score 1):

You can Create an `Live Folder` on Home Screen for App Shortcuts here is some useful links
which help you:

1.[android-developers](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/04/live-folders.html)

2.[AudioBooksLiveFolder](https://github.com/cesine/PDFtoAudioBook/blob/75981302129fe48ee315c322b03a8d66fce9f7e6/src/ca/openlanguage/pdftoaudiobook/ui/AudioBooksLiveFolder.java)

3.[betterandroid](http://code.google.com/p/betterandroid/source/browse/trunk/#trunk/Digg/src/com/betterandroid/openhome/digglive)

Answer (score 0):

ok, this maybe not valid requirement by not all Androids have "folders" try to look at a Galaxy S1 and Galaxy s2 
the S1 does not have a folders but the the S2 have them.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can go to Home Screen Using Intent and then You can create a folder.
You can go To Home Screen Using Following Code:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```